# Edit the form css of a django form

Tags: html, css, django, sass

so the submit button looks like this:

```
<input type="submit" id='register_submit' class= value="{% trans 'Submit' %}" /></div>
```

and normall I would use a class to specify what the button looks like, but this has its own class that I cannot touch. What can I do here to give it a new class so I can customize the button?

Answer (score 3):

An option would be to override the existing rule with a specific rule.  So, if your output HTML is:

```
<input type="submit" class="django-submit" />
```

You could wrap it to end up with:

```
<div class="my-button">
    <input type="submit" class="django-submit" />
</div>
```

And then use your `.my-button` class to create a more specific CSS rule:

```
.my-button .django-submit {
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #f00;
}
```

The [following demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6sVEu/) shows how the specific rule will override the generic rule.

Comment: +1, seems like the simplest way to do it. Or if you're just outputting `{{ form }}`, then wrap the whole thing in a `<div>` and update the CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the button a `style` attribute which will always take precedence over any `class` attribute.